# Find documents with arrays that contain a document with a particular field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find only documents that have all `'docs.foo'` present in a array.
In my example I should get only `_id: 2` result:

```
{  
    _id : 1,
    docs : [
        { bar : 2},
        { foo : 3, bar : 3}
    ]
},
{  
    _id : 2,
    docs : [
        { foo : 2, bar : 2},
        { foo : 3, bar : 3}
    ]
}
```

I thought about something like:

```
db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$nin: [$exists: false]}})
```

but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

```js
db.collection.find(function() { 
    return this.docs.length === this.docs.filter(function(doc) {
        return typeof(doc.foo) !== "undefined" && doc.foo !== null ;}).length 
})
```

---

Another way to do this is to run two queries: One to retrieve the `_id` of all those documents that don't match your criteria using the [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) method:

```js
var unwantedIds = db.collection.distinct( "_id", { "docs": { "$elemMatch": { "foo": { "$exists": false } } } } );
```

Then use the `$nin` operator to return all those documents that match your criteria.

```js
db.collection.find({ "_id": { "$nin": unwantedIds } } )
```

---

You can also use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method but this only work if you are on version 3.2 or newer because you need to use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

First stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage where you filter out those documents where the "foo" field is absent. This reduce the total number of documents that will be processed  down the pipe. The next and last stage is the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage. In this stage you need to use the `$size` operator to return the size of the the "docs" field and the size of the array of the sub-documents in where "foo" is present and return all those documents where the  two values are equals.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "docs.foo": { "$exists": true } } }, 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$eq": [ 
                { "$size": "$docs" }, 
                { "$size":  { 
                    "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$docs", 
                        "as": "doc", 
                        "cond": { 
                            "$ne": [ 
                                { "$ifNull": [ "$$doc.foo", null ] },
                                null 
                            ] 
                        } 
                    }
                }}
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

Comment: The `.aggregate()` should theortically run rings around the `$where` statement due to native operators and not JavaScript interpretation ( and thunking etc ). But to also be equivalent and fair, this should actually use `$where` as a query condition in the non-aggregate version along with the same `$exists` statement. Note that a similar `$setDifference` and `$map` "filter" also works here for pre MongoDB 3.2 but at least MongoDB 2.6 in this case. But this is what people should do here.