# How to find the all subdocuments contains particular key through $setDifference?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Per comments of this question [Find documents with arrays that contain a document with a particular field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451009/find-documents-with-arrays-that-contain-a-document-with-a-particular-field), `$setDifference` and `$map` should solve this issue. Here is the details of this question.

> I want to find only documents that have **all** `'docs.foo'` present in a array `docs`. Given the two documents as below
>
> ```
> {  
>     _id : 1,
>     docs : [
>         { bar : 2},
>         { foo : 3, bar : 3}
>     ]
> },
> {  
>     _id : 2,
>     docs : [
>         { foo : 2, bar : 2},
>         { foo : 3, bar : 3}
>     ]
> }
> ```

Here are my codes

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    {$project: {
        docs: {$setDifference: 
                [{$map:
                    {input: '$docs', 
                    as: 'item', 
                    in: {$cond: [{$ne: [
                                    {$ifNull: ['$$item.foo', null]}, 
                                    null]}, 
                               '$$item', 
                               null]}}
                }, 
                [null]
                ]
            }
    }}
])
```

However, the result is

```
{  
    _id : 1,
    docs : [
        { foo : 3, bar : 3}
    ]
},
{  
    _id : 2,
    docs : [
        { foo : 2, bar : 2},
        { foo : 3, bar : 3}
    ]
}
```

Only the `{bar: 2}` is removed from `_id: 1` document. I want the output is

```
{  
    _id : 1,
    docs : [ ]
},
{  
    _id : 2,
    docs : [
        { foo : 2, bar : 2},
        { foo : 3, bar : 3}
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to do that through `$setDifference`?

Comment: Well that is not what your code is going to to, and also not how you are explaining it. Is the logic you are possibly looking for that if "all" array members don't contain that key then exclude everything from that array? Because otherwise the result is exactly what it should be, and **only** the array member that does not contain the "foo" field is being removed.

Comment: Note also that commentary ( actually mine ) mentioned there was mostly in support of the answer there ( which also mentioned `$redact` and `$where` ) to "select" the "document" which met those conditions being where "all" the array members met those conditions. Your answer submitted there ( now deleted ) does not do that. And the `$setDifference` response would yield an array of "different size to the source", which also meets the conditions. No-one was looking for an empty array there, so that is where I think you missed the point.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, thank you for your explanation, What if I want to get the empty `docs` if any of subdocuments of `docs` does NOT have `foo` field. as the result shown in my question. Is it possible to do it through `setDifference`? Hope I make myself clearly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for here is a bit different to what the referenced question was asking, in that you purposely want to make an array "empty" if all documents contained within it do not match a set of conditions.

In this case the better operator here is [`$allElementsTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) , and you would apply it with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "docs": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$allElementsTrue": {
                        "$map": { 
                            "input": "$docs",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": { "$ifNull": [ "$$el.foo", false ] }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": "$docs",
                "else": { "$literal": [] }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

So rather than "filtering" array content, the logic basically tests each array element via `$map` and returns an array of `true/false` values. If "all elements are indeed `true`, then this will yield a singlular `true/false` value in response.

That is then considered by the ternary [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) which says when `true` ( all matched the condition ) then just present the array as it is already formed. But when this is `false` ( not everything matched ) instead return an empty array.

Pretty sure the `$literal` is not really required for an `"else"` argument and could just be written in as `[]`. But it's just being sure when I'm just typing the logic in here rather than testing.

But this logic would return the "empty" result since not "all" elements matched the requisite condition that all sub-documents in the array contained the `"foo"` key.